# how to group a list of dictionaries to get a list of their corresponding indices?

Tags: python, grouping

Have a list of dictionaries, something like this:

```
l = [{'a':25}, {'a':25}, {'b':30}, {'c':200}, {'b':30}]
```

want to find the distinct elements and their corresponding indices, something like this:

```
[
({'a':25}, [0,1]),
({'b':30}, [2,4]),
({'c':200}, [3]),
]
```

tried with itertools.groupby, but couldn't make it happen, perhaps I'm missing something, any other directions are great too.

Comment: Can there be dictionaries with the same key but different values? Should they be combined in the result?

Comment: Do the dictionaries always have just one key?

Comment: yes, different values can happen, no, not always one key

Comment: Please provide a more representative sample input and your expected output.

Comment: as shown, List[Tuple[Dict[str, int], List[int]]] would be prefereed

Comment: But that's not possible if e.g., you could have `{"a": 25}` and `{"a": 99}`. Should your result be `[({"a": 25}, [0]), ({"a": 99}, [1])]` or something else, like `[({"a": [25, 99]}), [0, 1]]`?

Comment: @ddejohn, the first option

Comment: @EzerK I believe my updated solution achieves your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this list of dictionaries:

```py
>>> dicts
[{'a': 3},
 {'d': 4, 'a': 3, 'c': 1},
 {'d': 8, 'c': 0, 'b': 9},
 {'c': 3, 'a': 9},
 {'a': 5, 'd': 8},
 {'d': 5, 'b': 5, 'a': 0},
 {'b': 7, 'c': 7},
 {'d': 6, 'b': 7, 'a': 6},
 {'a': 4, 'c': 1, 'd': 5, 'b': 2},
 {'d': 7}]
```

Assuming you want all indices of every instance of every dictionary's keys:

```py
idxs = {}
for i, d in enumerate(l):
    for pair in d.items():
        idxs.setdefault(pair, []).append(i)
```

This produces what I would consider more useful output, as it allows you to look up the indices of any specific key-value pair:

```py
{('a', 3): [0, 1],
 ('d', 4): [1],
 ('c', 1): [1, 8],
 ('d', 8): [2, 4],
 ('c', 0): [2],
 ('b', 9): [2],
 ('c', 3): [3],
 ('a', 9): [3],
 ('a', 5): [4],
 ('d', 5): [5, 8],
 ('b', 5): [5],
 ('a', 0): [5],
 ('b', 7): [6, 7],
 ('c', 7): [6],
 ('d', 6): [7],
 ('a', 6): [7],
 ('a', 4): [8],
 ('b', 2): [8],
 ('d', 7): [9]}
```

However, if you must convert to `List[Tuple[Dict[str, int], List[int]]]`, you can produce it very easily from the previous output:

```py
>>> [(dict((p,)), l) for p, l in idxs.items()]
[({'a': 3}, [0, 1]),
 ({'d': 4}, [1]),
 ({'c': 1}, [1, 8]),
 ({'d': 8}, [2, 4]),
 ({'c': 0}, [2]),
 ({'b': 9}, [2]),
 ({'c': 3}, [3]),
 ({'a': 9}, [3]),
 ({'a': 5}, [4]),
 ({'d': 5}, [5, 8]),
 ({'b': 5}, [5]),
 ({'a': 0}, [5]),
 ({'b': 7}, [6, 7]),
 ({'c': 7}, [6]),
 ({'d': 6}, [7]),
 ({'a': 6}, [7]),
 ({'a': 4}, [8]),
 ({'b': 2}, [8]),
 ({'d': 7}, [9])]
```

Comment: I think the key is supposed to be the whole dictionary, not just its first key.

Comment: I don't think OP was clear enough about that, and since dictionaries aren't hashable, I didn't bother converting them to tuples (also because it's not clear if all of OP's dictionaries are single key-value pairs). I think right now OP's question is too vague to start getting into the weeds.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the dictionaries into tuples so you can use them as keys in a dictionary. Then iterate over the list, adding the indexes to this dictionary.

```
locations_dict = {}
for i, d in enumerate(l):
    dtuple = tuple(d.items())
    locations_dict.setdefault(dtuple, []).append(i)

locations = [(dict(key), value) for key, value in locations_dict.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

indices = defaultdict(list)
for idx, val in enumerate(l):
    indices[tuple(*val.items())].append(idx)

print(indices)

# output
defaultdict(list, {('a', 25): [0, 1], ('b', 30): [2, 4], ('c', 200): [3]})
```

Comment: You don't need to spread the items when calling `tuple()`

Comment: @Barmar You do if you don't want a 1-tuple of `dict_items`

Comment: When I do `tuple({'a': 1, 'b': 2}.items())` I get `(('a', 1), ('b', 2))`

Comment: I get an error from `tuple(*{'a': 1, 'b': 2}.items())`

Comment: The argument to `tuple()` is a single iterable, not multiple elements to be put into a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

great idea with the dicts/defaultdicts, this also seems to work:

```
l = [{'a':25}, {'a':25}, {'b':30}, {'c':200}, {'b':30}, {'a': 25}]
sorted_values = sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: str(x[1]))
grouped = itertools.groupby(sorted_values, lambda x: x[1])
grouped_indices = [(k, [x[0] for x in g]) for k, g in grouped]
print(grouped_indices)
```

the idea is that once an array is sorted (keeping the original indices as additional details) itertools/linux groupby is preaty similar to sql/pandas groupby

Comment: This was a nice answer before the requirements changed lol.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it:

```
import ast
l = [{'a':25}, {'a':25}, {'b':30}, {'c':200}, {'b':30}]
n_dict = {}
for a, b in enumerate(l):
    n_dict[str(b)] = n_dict.get(str(b), []) + [a]

print(list(zip( [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in n_dict.keys()], n_dict.values() )))
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`?!

Comment: i couldn't use a dict as a key for another dict, so i converted it into a string and used eval() to convert the string back to a dict.

Comment: If you must, use `ast.literal_eval()`. There is never a good reason for using `eval()` and it is quite dangerous to suggest its use on Stack Overflow, which is read as gospel by many beginner coders that don't know any better.

Comment: After taking a look at eval()'s dangerousness, I edited the code. Thanks for the help and advice.